# Как сделать нижнюю рамку под верхней (белой) панелью приложения?

Tags: android, android-sdk, дизайн

Как сделать нижнюю рамку под верхней (белой) панелью приложения?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что-то мне лично не очень понятно о какой рамке идет речь, есть системный бар с часами, есть белый тулбар, где-то под ним должна быть рамка?

Comment: @Andrew, рамка должна быть под белым тулбаром

Comment: то есть у активности должна быть белая рамка?

Comment: Мне вообще не понятно о какой рамке идет речь. Может вы нарисуете хотя бы в paint?

Comment: Три лайка, а вопроса походу никто не понял... Напишите нормально вопрос, не стесняй написать несколько предложений!

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, готово

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто :) Берете вашу разметку, и в самый верх, или под тулбаром, если он есть вставляете этот виджет:

```
<View
   android:id="@+id/divider"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="2dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
   android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
```

тут вы можете менять размер, цвет, марджины можно настроить как вам нужно. В общем виде у меня это выглядит так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

      .........



</RelativeLayout>
```

В вашем случае установите нужный вам цвет и может что-то еще по вашему желанию :)

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!